# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS new kernel (5.15.0-58) leads to pink screen of death when NOT using second monitor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, multiple-monitors

I have a dual boot setup on an hp spectre-x360 from circa 2019 (13-ap0xxx).
When I initially installed Ubuntu, I was getting a pink screen of death with the default kernel (I believe it was 5.15.0-47 or something like that), but the secondary kernel which came with the distro, which was **5.15.0-43**, did work.

I changed my grub to make sure the secondary kernel was chosen by default and life was good for a little bit. Recently, without thinking about it too much, I upgraded the kernel to my current one, 5.15.0.-58, which lead me to my current problem:

When booting, if I have my secondary monitor connected (via a USB-C hub), everything boots just fine, however when I disconnect the USB-C hub I am back to the pink screen of death, seemingly at exactly the same step in the boot process as was happening with the initial installation. Strangely if I disconnect my monitor and the rest of the hub after booting, everything works normally.

To be sure what the source is I have already tried to boot with all configurations of the things connected to the USB-C hub: with and without the entire hub, with and without the wireless keyboard and mouse, and with or without the screen connected but without the hub (still via a USB-C adapter since that is the only port available). All setups where the screen was connected somehow worked, and all others failed.

This is obviously an issue since this is a laptop and I will often want to run it without my secondary monitor nearby. I can revert to the previous kernel, but I would hate to think that I will never be able to update my kernel without risking destroying my setup.

**EDIT:** It turns out the pink screen of death is not in fact as bad as it seems. If I ignore its existence and put in my login in details, the system comes back to life. It's still weird, and still hoping to solve this, but it's not as critical as I thought.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have also tried with and without the power adapter (which was connected via the usb-c hub originally), both on the hub and directly to the machine

Comment: Second update, turns out the pink screen of death is not in fact as it seems. If I ignore its existence and put in my login in details, the system comes back to life, still weird, still hoping to solve this, but not as lethal as I thought